# Time format with Highcharts

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to display some charts for my project.

But I have some problems to display a Basic Bar charts with only TIME (not the date) on Yaxis.
I searched some solutions but I didn't find the good one.
Currently, I put data in milliseconds.

But it gives me this result : 
http://s14.postimg.org/z4vissaht/Capture_d_cran_2013_05_31_21_24_01.png

As you can see, it says me "Invalid Date" and milliseconds are display but I would like it to be "00:00:00".
In the bottom of the chart, time is in the good format but it resets every 24hours whereas I don't want it. If milliseconds makes 62:00:00, I want it to be displayed like that.

I really need help, I don't know how to do that.

There is my jQuery code :

```
$('#chartTimeSpent').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo : 'chartTimeSpent',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Time spent per technicians ' + dateInterval
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: [ 'Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department','Department', ],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Time (hours)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                },
                type: 'datetime',

                dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                hour: '%H:%M:%S',
                day: '%H:%M:%S',
                week: '%H:%M:%S',
                month: '%H:%M:%S',
                year: '%H:%M:%S'
            }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        "" +
                        'Time: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x);
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -100,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [

                {name: 'Someone',
                     data: [300000 ,0,6720000 ,6600000 ,11400000 ,1500000 ,900000 ,0,0,300000 ,0,0, ] },{name: 'Someone',
                     data: [2100000 ,1800000 ,1200000 ,3300000 ,60600000 ,0,13920000 ,5400000 ,18900000 ,300000 ,0,0, ] },{name: 'Someone',
                     data: [9840000 ,223380000 ,300000 ,3120000 ,8760000 ,2460000 ,9300000 ,2820000 ,3960000 ,1320000 ,900000 ,540000 , ] },            ]
        });
```

**EDITED** : [last jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nURBY/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT Based on desired outcome:
Your main issue is is that you have a lot of js errors (extra commas, etc). Fixed those. Now, the reason why your chart is not showing (as far as I can tell) is that your `chart.title` is expecting a var to be appending to it (`text: 'Time spent per technicians ' + dateInterval`) and at least in the jsFiddle and example code you give you do not define it.

I have updated a new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/nURBY/) with what I think it is you want. Note that the values in your table list do not match the javascript times in your series data.

Your data does not contain any time values. You are going to either include that in your data series as `[[time1, value], [time2, value]...]` or you are going to need to assign a starting position for the xAxis ([pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart)) and also tell it what to each data point increment is ([pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval)) - assuming your data is separated in time uniformly - like this:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
            }
        },
```

Highly recommended you read the API documentation found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).

Edited answer:

You have much other stuff that is wrong with your chart here:
Your yAxis cannot be of `type: 'datetime'`. Even though you think the times are plotted on the yAxis because this is a BAR chart it is still the xAxis. Remove the `type` and `dateTimeLabelFormats` items from the yAxis and put in the xAxis instead.

Remove the `categories:` section for your xAxix. You cannot mix datetime and categories.

You have extra commas in the series data point list and an extra comma after the last series item.

You need to assign the plotOptions in the series section.

Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/fPNMz/) for example. I would recommend jsFiddle or any other "live" javascript service to test your code.

This is to show the time as just straight hours:minutes without concern for day part:
Remove the `type: 'datetime'` and the label formatter stuff for house/min/sec etc.
Add the following -

```
labels: {
            overflow: 'justify',
            formatter: function () {
                var seconds = (this.value / 1000) | 0;
                this.value -= seconds * 1000;

                var minutes = (seconds / 60) | 0;
                seconds -= minutes * 60;

                var hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
                minutes -= hours * 60;
                return hours;
            }
        }
```

To handle the dataLabels we need to do some other reformatting. Now, take this with a grain of salt as I am not a js expert and I am sure this is overly verbose and can be done with a simple method.

```
formatter: function () {
                    if (this.y === 0) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else {
                    var hours = (((this.y / 1000) / 60) / 60).toFixed(2);
                    var hourPortion = hours.toString().split(".")[0];
                    var minPortion = hours.toString().split(".")[1];
                    var minPortionUsed = (parseInt(hours.toString().split(".")[1]) * 0.6).toFixed(0);
                        if (minPortionUsed < 10) {
                            minPortionUsed = '0' + minPortionUsed.toString();
                        }
                    return hourPortion + ':' + minPortionUsed;
                    }
                }
```

See this updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/nURBY/9/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand your first advice.
What's supposed to be "time" and "value"? Each person has 1 duration for each department in my case (I can put it in milliseconds or 00:00:00).

I tried to include the plotOptions like you said but it gives me nothing.

Comment: @D3n, updated answer. Your data points need an x/y value and since this data is time based your x value should be time. If you want to set your data up as time spent in each department by each person then you need to remove provide a bit more info.

Comment: I did see your live demo on jsFiddle but there is no longer departments display if I remove the categories. I just followed the basic exemple of Highcharts and they put categories in xAxis.

For a better look, here a link of data I want to put in this chart :
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/EeuCr/)

Comment: Ahh! Now I see, you want to put each of the Technician items as a series, with the Department on the xAxix (category), and the Time Spent on the yAxix formatted to be human readable time. Yes, that is completely doable. Will update answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! That almost what I wanted, this would be perfect if the values were display next to each bar.
So I trying to add a formatter to the dataLabels in plotOptions but atm it doesn't work, I think i'm doing bad

Comment: Do you want the data labels to be part of the chart or appear when you hover over the point? See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels for examples.

Comment: Yeah I would them to be part of the chart, I was already seeking on that page.
Also, do you think it's possible to display hours on yAxis by add them. Exemple : one technician has 80:00:00, then display 80:00:00 but not 3days and 8Hours...

Comment: Yep, you would do that with the dataLabels.formatter function.

Comment: Sorry, it's me again. I tried several solutions but I haven't been able to exceed the 24:00:00 so far. If ou have an idea, I'm not against one last hint :/ I have edited my initial post with my last jsFiddle result.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, that's way better that what I tried. Thanks again for your help wergeld, you solved all my problems! :)