# Hours: Mintues: Seconds in HighCharts Bargraph

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to graph the length of times that each employee spends on the phone in a bargraph using Highcharts. I am not getting any errors, but the graph is not drawing. Any advice moving forward would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- create the highcharts object -->

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({



            chart: {
                type: 'column',
             backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['May 2013', 'June 2013', 'July 2013', 'August 2013', 'September 2013', 'October 2013', 'November 2013', 'December 2013', 'January 2014', 'February 2014', 'March 2014', 'April 2014', ]
            },
            yAxis: {
            // type: 'datetime', //y-axis will be in milliseconds
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
               second: '%H:%M:%S',
               minute: '%H:%M:%S',
               hour: '%H:%M:%S',
               day: '%H:%M:%S',
               week: '%H:%M:%S',
               month: '%H:%M:%S',
               year: '%H:%M:%S'
            },
                title: {
                    text: 'Time Spent on Phone'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} calls</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [
            { name: 'Michelle', data: ["02:19:36", "02:37:26", "01:57:27", "02:23:49", "02:10:49", "02:32:33", "02:16:10", "01:25:01", "00:50:49", "0", "0", "0", ] },{ name: 'Kim', data: ["04:53:56", "09:21:07", "10:32:46", "10:30:21", "09:15:12", "09:15:57", "06:19:16", "08:59:23", "06:11:48", "0", "0", "0", ] },{ name: 'Katie', data: ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "08:00:14", "03:59:01", "0", "0", "0", ] },            ]
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include jquery and then highcharts js files?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The outline of the graph displays, but no bars are drawn.

Comment: My answer here may be helpful for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227847/how-to-pass-time-in-highcharts/21268457#21268457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `yAxis.type: 'datetime'` and you need to format your `series.data` to be a valid time javascript time. Currently you have yAxis set to just be values (default) and your data is actually a string ("02:19:36" for example). This needs to be converted to a javascript time.

Edit - example of [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

To convert your first entry for 'Michelle' use:
`Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 2, 19, 36)`

Since you don`t care about year/month/day but the function requires year and month I just set them to 0. Replace all your string dates such that your`data` looks like:

```
data: [Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 2, 19, 36), Date.UTC(....), etc]
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/BcB8h/1/) is an updated fiddle with just one set of data. Noticed I changed series type to 'line. The 'column' type was acting funny.

[Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/BcB8h/2/) the 'column' type issue but setting arbitrary yAxis min year/month/day and setting the data points to use that same value so that the only difference is the time.

Comment: That is the part that I am stuck on though.  Where and how do I convert that time?

Comment: You can use split() function on string, then paste elements intio Date.UTC(). Second solution is using Date.parse()

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm lost with this stuff.  Can you give me an example using the code I have above how to do this?  I'm not a javascript guy.

Comment: Thank you...I feel as if I'm really close, but we have some employees who are on the phone for over 30 hours on the phone...and the graph messes up because when the hours hit 24, it rolls over back to 0 and goes back to the next day.

Comment: Okay, this is a different requirement. Please see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864636/time-format-with-highcharts. The basic idea is to change your yValues to a javascript time value - not a date timestamp. Basically convert your hours/min/sec to js time which is trivial. No need to include year/month/day.